# WP как создать repeat группу полей?

Tags: php, wordpress

без плагинов, вот как пример ниже чтобы выглядел, только с возможностью добавлять/удалять группу полей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создайте свой метабокс.

Comment: создать не проблема, особенно поля по отдельности, но не понимаю, как именно группу создавать, вкладывать в массив? но как это впринципе будет выглядеть?

Comment: При сохранении метабокса считываете все поля, сохраняете в массив. Добавление/удаление полей - через js.

Answer (score 1):

В целом процесс простой. Делаете поле с `name="field[]"`. Добавляете кнопку `+` для добавления. При клике на кнопку копируете поле и вставляете после. Чтобы не изобретать велосипед поищите лучше `repeater js` какой-нибудь